# Passing multiple arrays/lists into a function (python)

Tags: python, arrays, string, function

```
# Lists
Prod_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Loc_list = ['L:\\Team\\1','L:\\Team\\2','L:\\Team\\3']

# New directory 
d = date.today()
dateform = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")

newpath = backup+r'\\'+dateform
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

# Copy Function
def Copy_File(original_loc, product_name, destination):
    for i in original_loc
        sht.copy2(original_loc+r'\\'+product_name+r' Daily Excursions.csv',destination+r'\\'+product_name+r' Daily Excursions.csv')


Copy_File(Loc_list, Prod_list, newpath)
```

So as is, this doesn't work. I get an error about how I can't concatenate a list with a string. And obviously that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to concatenate the constituents of both my lists (indexed the same so i can use the same counter). I just didn't want to use a for loop if I didn't have to.

I still need to do the matching index iterations of product_name

Comment: `for i=1,i<=N Items(original_loc),i++,` is not even a valid Python syntax

Comment: I didn't meant to include that line, I was asking someone in person that I work with if I would have to do something like a for loop.

But in any case, your answer is *so* helpful. >.> Thanks for all the helpful information leading me to a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the `original_loc` list items you have to use a for statement, but you don't use the right syntax, please read the tutorial about `for` statements at:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Yup I got that. But if I attempt to do for i in original_loc: then I am only perofrming iterations over one of my lists. How do I do it for more than one?

Comment: You can nest flow controls constructions. In the tutorial I linked to you there's an example with a nested if in the for statement. You can nest a `for` statement in a `for` statement so you can iterate over each products while iterating over each locations.